# SwiftでUITextViewのattributedTextの内容をリッチテキストファイル(test.rtf)として保存するには？

Tags: swift

リッチテキストファイル(testRichText.rtf)の内容をUITextViewに表示することは、
下記のコードによって実現できました。
逆にUITextViewのattributedTextの内容をリッチテキストファイルとして
出力したいのですが、方法が分かりません。

```
    if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("testRichText", withExtension: "rtf") {
        let opts = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType]            
        if let s = NSAttributedString(fileURL: url, options: opts, documentAttributes: nil, error: nil) {
            self.testUiText.attributedText = s
        }
    }
```

下記の投稿を見て、Objective-Cの場合の記載方法は載っていたのですが、
Swiftの場合、どのように記述すれば良いかが分かりません。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134217/objective-c-how-to-create-rtf-from-nsattributedstring

```
NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"YOLO" attributes:nil];
NSData *data = [str dataFromRange:(NSRange){0, [str length]} documentAttributes:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType} error:NULL];
[data writeToFile:@"/me.rtf" atomically:YES];
```

Comment: 自己解決した場合は、じぶんで回答して、その回答を承認する（チェックをつける）ことで、クローズするらしいです。（あいまいですみません）

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。自分の回答は48時間経たないと承認できないようです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決しました。

```
let opts = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType]

//NSDataに変換
var data = self.testUiText.attributedText.dataFromRange(NSMakeRange(0, self.testUiText.attributedText.length), documentAttributes: opts, error: nil)

//ファイル名
var fileName = "test.rtf"

//Documentsまでのパス取得
let paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
let documentsPath = paths1[0] as String

//Documentsまでのパスにファイル名を結合
let filePath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)

println(filePath)

//RTFファイル出力
data?.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)
```